# Relevancy searching in elastic search,

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

Currently i am implementing product search in my application using elastic-search,i was able to implement basic search by applying steamers(to get root terms) and analyzers(remove 's' and stuff like that), but when searching for products like "Red Shrimp" i am getting "red shrimps" , "shrimps" and also some unrelated products which contain "Red"(Red gram,Red onion,Red battey) which shouldn't happen.
Can any one suggest me how to eliminate this irrelevant section of results,I am grateful to any valid suggestion.

Thanks,
I

Comment: You can search your full query in `"` then it will match the exact word.

Comment: Doing so will eliminate partial token search,which is ""red shrimp"" will not return 'shrimp' it only matches for shrimp which is not i wanted, i wanted both types of shrimps to be detected  but products like "red rice" & "Red powder" to be excluded, my qsn is how can i impart this intelligence to my search.

Comment: On what basis you're deciding which one to include and which one to exclude?

Comment: currently i am planning to search based on "'categories"(shrimp belongs to a category and rice belongs to diff category) which i should identify from search string and proceed my search accordingly.But it doesn't sound like a complete solution, i want to know and further implement how big players implement such sort of functionalities(intelligent search)

Comment: So you can make a separate field for the `category` store category there. and while filtering put a filter on the category. and then you can search.

Comment: @UnknownUser currently i am doing exactly the same, but still that sort of search is not a intelligent search,in a scenario where we search for "Long", term long may be in multiple categories  like "long shrimps","long sleeves"..etc, but when only long is searched we should not show all the products which have long, but rather we should show most meaningful product(eg apparels), in the same way there will be many scenarios, i want my search to identify the term and give intelligent responses.

Answer (score 0):

you can use elastic "Common Terms Query" with minimum_should_match option

Reference Link : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html